# python モジュールとは

Tags: python

現在pythonを勉強しています。
モジュールの意味がわかりませんので
教えて頂けたら助かります。

Answer (score 1):

かなり広い意味で使われる言葉だと思いますが、

[公式ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/modules.html)より

> モジュールは Python の定義や文が入ったファイルです。ファイル名はモジュール名に接尾語 .py がついたものになります。

が、先ず最初にくるイメージになるでしょう。

あとは、モジュールを利用する場面の方が多いと思いますが、その場面では、`import` でモジュールを取り込んで使う形になります。

例えば、sys モジュールで定義された機能を使って、コマンドライン入力変数を利用したい場合

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[0])
```

として、sys モジュールの機能を使うわけです。

Comment: 有難うございました。
だいぶ理解出来ました。
これからも宜しくお願い致します。